# Make Windows boot after sector-wise copying from 4 GB flash card to 8 GB

Tags: bios, dd, disk-image, windows-xp-embedded

I've Windows Embedded XP system installed on a 4 GB Compact Flash card (which is visible as IDE drive to operating system). I've used `dd` to move it sector-to-sector to another flash drive which is 8 GB, but it cannot boot from it saying "NTLDR is missing". After [some googling](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=25072#p112035) I found an idea that it is CHS geometry change what is to blame.

I've checked BIOS setup and looked up for auto detected settings for both old and new flash cards. Here they are:

```
            Old:     New:
-------------------------
Cylinder    8006    15538
Head          16       16
Precomp        0        0
Landing     8005    15537
Sector        63       63
```

I've switched drive mode from "Auto" to "CHS" and tried to manually set the 8 GB drive the same geometry as the old one has, but (unsurprisingly) things just got worse ("NTLDR is missing" become "SYSTEM DISK FAILURE").

I know there are `fixboot` and `fixmbr` for situations like this, but is it possible to boot the system keeping exact drive copy unchanged?

Comment: does `fixboot` and `fixmbr` resolve the problem?

Comment: Is 8 GB flash drive's [partition marked active](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc779300(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_CMD)?

Comment: @Vinayak: yes, partition is marked active (I've checked), it would be strange if it is not active after sector-to-sector copying.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm unable to check right now but they once solved very similar problem for me.